# I created a code to perfectly complete a human benchmark quiz. Why does it fail?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The following is a code i made in an attempt to get a perfect score on this website:
https://humanbenchmark.com/tests/verbal-memory

For some reason it fails every time i run it and i cant figure out why.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\user\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://humanbenchmark.com/tests/verbal-memory")

word_list = []

time.sleep(2)

start_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[4]/button")
start_button.click()

def click_new():
    new_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")
    new_button.click()

def click_seen():
    seen_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]")
    seen_button.click()

while True:
    current_word = driver.find_element_by_class_name("word")
    if current_word.text in word_list:
        click_seen()
    else:
        click_new()
    word_list.append(current_word.text)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: What exactly fails? The script? The test? Is there a message along with the failure?

Comment: It fails the test with a terrible score

Comment: I am new to selenium and now at 23:20 too tired to figure out the webdriver issues, but a) Did you try to print the `current_word.text` after it has been obtained? Is it what you expect? b) You can indent the `word_list.append(...)` to keep duplicates out.

Comment: @Dr.V a) Printing the current_word.text string prints exactly what it should - the word that is on screen. b) Will do mate, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add the word to the list before clicking on the button:

```
while True:
    current_word = driver.find_element_by_class_name("word")
    if current_word.text in word_list:
        click_seen()
    else:
        word_list.append(current_word.text)
        click_new()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Seemingly, current_word is actually updated in the moment you click the button, and then it's already the new word that is added to the list. This one you will then think to have seen, so it always selected `click_seen()`.

I let it run for some time, but I leave the honour to you to break the record and screw the statistics :-DDD.

Comment: Thank you so much you legend. Actual technical genius.